# db4o: Same class, different java projects

Tags: db4o

I have two different Java Applications A and B. They should use the same Database for user management (If the User has an account in Application A, he also has an account in Application B and vice versa).

Both Application A and B have exactly the same User class. But when I create an User in Application A I can't retrieve this same User in Application B and vice-versa.

I've read in a [forum](http://developer.db4o.com/Forums/tabid/98/aft/2743/Default.aspx):

> db4o is able to do this. Different application can use the same
>   database and access data of others "if you provide refferences" to the
>   projects. I mean if you put your entity in a class library and add it
>   as references to projects it wont be a problem

How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The way I found out to get solve this problem was the following:

1) I exported the package (I will call it package P) with the classes I wanted both project to have into a .jar file
2) I deleted the package P from both projects A and B
3) I imported the .jar file with the package P in both projects A and B

Now, everything works as I wanted: I make an account in project A and I also can use the same account in project B.

Comment: Could you add your solution as an answer? (You will have to wait three more hours to do so, as a new user.) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

db4o stores the fully qualified name of classes so if you want to access the same database from two (or more) different apps (with different package structures for the model classes) you have basically 2 options:

- Have your model classes as a separate project used by the applications;
- Configure [aliases](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-7.12/java/api/com/db4o/config/CommonConfiguration.html#addAlias%28com.db4o.config.Alias%29)

Hope this helps.

Adriano